# Visual Studio Code :: Configure Kusto Connection

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm new to Kusto.

I'm trying to follow this guide that should help me identify [unused resources on Azure](https://dev.to/omiossec/detecting-unused-azure-resources-2mdk).

The first command is pretty easy:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/disks"
```

But it fails miserably with the error: `Request is invalid and cannot be executed. ('where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'resources')`

[image]

I have tried with other resources:

```
Samples
SampleIoTData
SampleMetrics
ContosoSales
SampleLogs
```

[image]

But non seems working.

I have also tried

- Add Azure  Data Explorer cluster
- Add Azure Application Insights

[image]

And none seems to work.

So how do you connect to your Azure Subscription through Visual Studio Code and Kusto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Kusto** was created within Microsoft and used internally within Microsoft.
**Log Analytics** & **Application Insights** (as of today, components of **Azure Monitor**) are Microsoft's SaaS (Software as a Service) that use **Kusto** as back-end.
**Azure Resource Graph** is another Microsoft's SaaS that uses **Kusto** as back-end.
Those SaaS externalize (different) subsets of the **Kusto** query language (**KQL**).
Those SaaS are unrelated.
**Azure Data Explorer** (abbrevated **ADX**) is Microsoft's offering of **Kusto** as PaaS (Platform as a Service), to its customers.

Some reading:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Data_Explorer

---

There is a Visual Studio Code plugin that supports executing KQL queries against **ADX** clusters & **Application Insight**.

---

Samples, SampleIoTData etc. are databases of an **ADX** publicly available cluster, called **[Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-ui-samples-gallery)**.

---

**resources** is a table of **Azure Resource Graph**.
You can query it through the Azure Portal:
https://portal.azure.com/#view/HubsExtension/ArgQueryBlade

I'm not familiar with a formal option to query it from Visual Studio Code, but if you search on the web, you can find some projects developed by individuals.

Comment: Hi David and thank you. Using the `Azure Resource Graph Explorer` made the trick. However I'm still unable to use the VS Code plugin as I cannot connect to my account. Are you able to query Azure through VS Code? Thank you

Comment: I'll post a new answer with a detailed explanation

Comment: No worries, I hope to see you at Data.TLV Summit 2022 (http://datatlv.com/) in Tel Aviv if you are around. Thanks

Comment: Posted. At the moment I don't have concrete plans to join the Daya.TLV summit (or any other summit in the next 10 years, for that matter ), but we'll see...

Answer (score 3):

- Click the "Extensions" button, search for "kusto notebooks" and click "Install"

[image: Install]

- Press the "Kusto" button and then the "Add Cluster" button

[image: Kusto]

- Select the 1st connection type ("Azure Data Explorer Cluster")

[image: ADX]

- Enter the cluster URL

[image: Cluster URL]

- Note the newly create cluster and databases on the left

[image: Help]

- Click the "Explorer" button and then create a new file with `.knb` suffix.

[image: help.knb]

- In your newly created file, click the "Configure Kusto Connection" button

[image: Configure Kusto Connection]

- Select the require connection

[image: Connection]

- Select the required database

[image: Database]

- Add a "Code" cell, write your code and execute it

[image: Code]

Comment: Tested successfully on my personal ADX cluster as well.

Comment: Thank you. I still cannot connect from VS Code but that might be because of my permissions. I hope your answer will help more people

Comment: The Help cluster is publicly available, give it a try