# Kusto - Get Average and Count in the same row

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

Using Kusto, I want to write a query to see the average duration of events and total count of those events as well. I am able to do it in two queries like this but is it possible to do this in 1 query?

```
dependencies
| where type == 'SQL' and operation_Name == 'something'
| summarize avg(duration) by data
| order by data asc

dependencies
| where type == 'SQL' and operation_Name == 'something'
| summarize count() by data
| order by data asc
```

This is giving me what I want in two separate results. For example I get this:

```
A 1.2
B 1.4
C 4.5
```

and

```
A 5
B 90
C 78
```

but what I want is this

```
A 1.2 5
B 1.4 90
C 4.5 78
```

Comment: You might want to read this in order to get your terms straight https://stackoverflow.com/a/73418510/6336479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator#syntax) operator for syntax

```
T | summarize [SummarizeParameters] [[Column =] Aggregation [, ...]] [by [Column =] GroupExpression [, ...]]
```

---

```
dependencies
| where type == 'SQL' and operation_Name == 'something'
| summarize avg(duration), count() by data
| order by data asc
```

Comment: Nice, so I was just supposed to add [,count()] before "by data". Same as SQL lol :D.